# How to group by multiple columns using bigquery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table with two date columns, one region column and multiple metrics.

I want to group by each date, and then by region then metrics.

The table looks like below:

| Date | Campaign Date | Region | total spend | total clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08/09/2022 | 06/09/2022 | a | 30 | 20 |
| 07/09/2022 | 07/09/2022 | a | 20 | 28 |
| 08/09/2022 | 06/09/2022 | b | 38 | 35 |
| 07/09/2022 | 07/09/2022 | b | 25 | 26 |

I want to create a table like this where first group by date and campaign date, the group by different region, finally show the metrics:

| Date | Campaign_Date | Region | total_spend | total clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/09/2022 | 06/09/2022 | a | 30 | 20 |
| 07/09/2022 | 06/09/2022 | b | 38 | 35 |
| 08/09/2022 | 07/09/2022 | a | 20 | 28 |
| 08/09/2022 | 07/09/2022 | b | 25 | 26 |

The code is below:

```
SELECT Date,
       Campaign_Date,
       Region,
       SUM(spend) AS total_spend,
       SUM(clicks) AS total_clicks
FROM df
GROUP BY Date, Campaign_Date, Region
```

Expecting a grouped by date, Campaign Date then separate by region

Comment: I don't see the question!

Answer (score 0):

Take Spend out of the group by and add region in.  Generally, you want to group by the columns you are not aggregating

```
SELECT Date,
       Campaign_Date,
       Region,
       SUM(spend) AS total_spend,
       SUM(clicks) AS total_clicks
FROM df
GROUP BY Date, Campaign_Date, Region
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo mistake on my question, updated it now

Comment: What is not working?  This should result in you target output